# How to use max function in such condition?

Tags: mysql, optimization

My query is

```
select * from guestuser union select * from olduser ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

1. Is that correct query to find last userid from different table have different userid?
2. can i change query using max function. or optimize it?

table1 - userid -  1, 4, 5... etc

table2 - userid -  2, 3, 6...etc

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: actually i am fetching all data instead of userid in my script, thats why it takes too much time. for that i want optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the simple case, [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) on sub-selects may perform best:

```
SELECT GREATEST((SELECT userid FROM guestuser ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1)
               ,(SELECT userid FROM olduser   ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1)) AS userid;
```

If you want to `change query using max function`:

```
SELECT GREATEST((SELECT max(userid) FROM guestuser)
               ,(SELECT max(userid) FROM olduser)) AS userid;
```

Probably the same performance, but a bit shorter.
I would probably use this, just because it's shortest.

Or closer to your original:

```
SELECT max(userid) AS userid
FROM  (
  (SELECT userid FROM guestuser ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1)
   UNION  ALL
  (SELECT userid FROM olduser   ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1)
  ) sub;
```

Or just:

```
SELECT max(userid) AS userid
FROM  (
   SELECT userid FROM guestuser
   UNION  ALL
   SELECT userid FROM olduser
  ) sub;
```

Or even (almost like what you had):

```
SELECT userid FROM guestuser
UNION  ALL
SELECT userid FROM olduser
ORDER  BY userid DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

The last two may be slower.

Comment: +1 for another solution, but I don't think that there will be a measurable performance difference.

Comment: @tombom: Yeah, all of these (maybe except for the last 2 of my variants) should perform similarly.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

```
select userid from (
(select userid from guestuser order by userid DESC LIMIT 1)
union all 
(select userid from olduser ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 1)
) sq 
order by userid DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: am i doing in wrong way? what is `sq`?

Comment: sq is just an alias for the subquery. In this case it's needed. You're doing it wrong in the sense, that you're getting every row from table guestuser and just one row from olduser. The order by and limit is just applied to second query in the union. I also changed `union` to `union all`, as this does not care about duplicates. It has better performance than just `union`.

Comment: thanks. but when we use alias we write `AS` in-between table name and temporary table name. but u didn't used?

Comment: You can write `AS`, but it's not necessary.